# Enterprise Architect: broken link after updating from Version control

Tags: enterprise-architect

Scenario:

- Enterprise Architect 10 model configured with CVS for Version control and for team working (each package is version controlled).
- Package A contains an activity diagram. This activity diagram contains an hyperlink to a sequence diagram.
- The linked sequence diagram is defined in Package B

Problem:

- Another user update its model (get all latest)
- The link is broken: the user sees the link in the activity diagram as a note. Double clicking on it, the user is not redirected to the sequence, but a note is opened. The note's content is just the name of the (originally) linked sequence diagram.

The problem is not systematic. It happens often, but not always.

Comment: If you have a shared model, DON'T use get all latest. Drop VC, use EA locking and a nightly snapshot for VC (which is superfluous anyway).

Comment: @ThomasKilian: in my case Version controlled model is a project's requirement. No way to drop it.

Comment: I know those arguments. I fought against them and I'm tired of it. But every time I convinced customers to do it, all their issues were gone. You might find my comments on Sparx' forum if you're lucky with the search.

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latest version. In v11 there were major improvements to this known issue.

IIRC v12 also has some minor tweaks to the VC system.

One very common cause is using classifiers iso objects in sequence diagrams.

Comment: Thank you, actually i knew the sequence issue (http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/standard_uml_models/sequence_diagrams_and_version_.html), so I used objects instead of classifier.
I was surprised to find a similar issue on activity diagrams too.
I hope updating to 11 will fix the problem.